# dotenv process.env variable undefined in globally installed custom CLI tool

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I'm migrating one of my CLI tools over to a global installation so that it can be installed globally and used anywhere on my system. Most of my `src` files include `require('dotenv').config()` at the top of them, but for some reason the `env` is undefined now that it's installed globally.

What am I missing?

My package JSON looks like:

```json
{
  "name": "scoop",
  "version": "1.9.0",
  "main": "bin/scoop.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.20.0",
    "cli-spinners": "2.4.0",
    "commander": "6.1.0",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "log-symbols": "4.0.0",
    "ora": "5.1.0",
    "readline": "1.3.0"
  },
  "bin": {
    "scoop": "./bin/scoop.js"
  }
}
```

bin/scoop.js then contains the following at the top:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

require('dotenv').config();
const forms = require('../src/utils/LocateForms');
...
```

And I'm loading in additional JS src files that are exported, I've got an `.env` in my project my my custom variables just come up as undefined now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's expected behaviour.

The default `path` value for `dotenv` is `Default: path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env')` according to the [GitHub readme](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#path).

Now `process.cwd` changes depending upon from where you execute the executable file.
For example if u start `node /a/b/c.js` then the cwd would be `/a/b` and if you start it from `node /a/b/d/c.js` the cwd would be `/a/b/d`.

So, in order to get the the `.env` file that you want either you have to store the `.env` file in a common area like `~/.yourenv` like most other executables do(think `.bashrc`).

Or, you can try to get the installation folder and get the `.env` file using an absolute path.

For example you can try to import `npm` and get the `prefix` to find out the installation folder.

```
var npm = require("npm")
npm.load({}, function (er) {
    if (er) return handleError(er)
    console.log(npm.get('prefix'));
})
```

Or, you can use some package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-installed-path